# Shopware 6 Server setup problem with bin/console

Tags: symfony, shopware

when I'm installing Shopware 6 on my live server and try to fire the `bin/console` command I get the following errors:

PHP Warning:  Unsupported declare 'strict_types' in ...
PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected 'class' (T_CLASS), expecting identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or '{' or '$' in ...

I've already checked my PHP version because I thought it could be caused by an old version but it is on 7.3.

Do you know what is wrong there?
Am I missing something probably? I re-installed the whole shop again but I'm still not able to fire those commands.

Thanks

Comment: So php --version is yielding a version of 7.3?  Because the server version of php can be different than the command line version.  And you are not using docker or any sort of deployment tool?

Comment: I am not using docker or deployment tools.
The command line version shows 5.4 and the phpinfo shows 7.3

Comment: So that is the problem.  Depending on the host operating system, you need to probably adjust PATH to point to the 7.3 version.  And while perhaps a bit off-topic, if you have control of the system then you may as well update everything to php 7.4.

Comment: okay I fixed it by adding a php alias to php 7.3 on my server. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The PHP Version used in the web server can complete differ from the console one. Especially many server providers have left the operating system distributed version on cli and compiled their own versions in order to support newer or older versions than the system's one.

So, first steps should be to determine which php version you really use in your terminal:

```
which php
```

This command shows you in where all `php` is located in your `$PATH`variable paths.

You could also try

```
php -v
```

Which shows you the php version. If there's is nothing than just the php version it's a typical sign that it is unconfigured.

Then you may look in your server's provider documentation where they have located a configured php 7.3 for the cli. It is also possible that it is not in your `$PATH` variable. If not, please add it as the first path, so that this path wins. It is needed, because Shopware use php scripts directly with a shell script `shebang` line, which determine the php binary from `$PATH`

If your provider use `update-alternatives` update the symlink with the command to 7.3 or  let it be done by the server provider.